# SQL query to add calculated field which compares data rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

The heading of this question is probably poorly worded as I am finding it difficult to explain concisely what I want, other than to provide some demo data.

I have a query which returns the following data from a sql table:

```
ID    Job    User    Amount

1     101    Bob     100
2     101    Pete    500
3     102    Bob     400
4     102    Pete    200
5     101    Pete    850
6     102    Bob     650
```

What I want is the query to also return an additional field called (Difference), which contains the difference between the Amount in consecutive entries for the same User and Job.  Hence the data I would like returned would be as follows:

```
ID    Job    User    Amount   Diff

1     101    Bob      100     100
2     101    Pete     500     500
3     102    Bob      400     400
4     102    Pete     200     200
5     101    Pete     850     350
6     102    Bob      650     250
```

In the first four rows, the Diff is the same as the Amount because each is the first entry per User per Job (hence the Difference is calculated with reference to a starting Amount of nil in effect).

The last two lines contain information for a User and Job combination that have appeared in the table previously, and hence Diff is calculated as follows:

```
Job 101    User Pete    850 - 500 = 350
Job 102    User Bob     650 - 400 = 250
```

I've never had to compare data from rows like this in a SQL query before so don't really know where to start.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Added

Please note the Amount is not a running total.  It is a subjective assessment made periodically of the value of a User's input in each particular job.  It is possible that the Amount could in fact go down from one assessment to the next.  What I want is a query that returns the difference between successive assessments 'Amounts'.

Alternative Explanation

I'm looking to return a history trail of movements in the Amount assessed.  So another example, looking at a single Job and User is as follows:

```
Job    User    Amount    Movement

101    Bob      100       100
101    Bob      500       400
101    Bob      400      (100)
101    Bob    1,000       600
```

However, as per the original example, this information will need to be extracted from a table which contains many Jobs and Users all intermingled.

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: Also, why is ID=5 Amount 850 but ID=6 Amount 650? For ID 5, you have summed Amounts for previous 101,Pete pairs. But for ID 6, you have the  current amount. And is it "first value" per pair? Or "previous value" per pair?

Comment: Lacking a date/time column, is _consecutive_ defined by the order of `ID` values?

Comment: The Amounts are individual to the User and are not Job Totals, so ID 5 and 6 are correct.  There is also a Date field (and others) but I didn't include in order to keep the sample data concise.

Comment: @PJW: this doesn't make sense. per user, 850 is not the sum of 500+200+359. 650 is not the sum of 100+400+659). per user, per job, 850=500+350. OK. But 650 <> 400+650. Not my downvote BTW. Yet.

Comment: Seriously!!!  I can't believe people are making assumptions about the implementation of this code and down voting because THEY do not understand it.  The data is correct!  The 'Amount' is a subjective assessment at different stages of a job's life.  It is NOT a sum of previous amounts.  So a manager may say that Bobs work on Job 101 is worth 300 one month, then a reassessment of the situation a month later means it is valued at 500.  I need the query to calculate the movement from one assessment to the next i.e. 200 in this example.

Comment: Wow. Downvote now. We can't get your desired result because you have given us inconsistent data. Fix it or delete it or have it closed for you

Comment: My question is simple really, subjective assessments are made each month of the Amount, which could go down as well as up.  I want to return the difference between subsequent assessments on the same job and same user.

Comment: Then calculate it in the client, unless you're generating directly from SQL -> report on screen (always bad juju in my experience)

Comment: @HABO  Yes consecutive is based on ID as it is possible more than one assessment may be made on the same day, so Date is probably the wrong field to use for establishing consecutive assessments.

Comment: You still have the discrepancy then between 350 and 850 in the first 2 data sets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012, try this

This assumes that ID=5 value is wrong in your example

For "previous value" per pair

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID int, Job int, Username varchar(10), Amount int);
INSERT @t
VALUES
    (1, 101, 'Bob', 100), (2, 101, 'Pete', 500), (3, 102, 'Bob', 400),
    (4, 102, 'Pete', 200), (5, 101, 'Pete', 850), (6, 102, 'Bob', 650);

SELECT
    t1.*,
    t1.Amount - ISNULL(LAG(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Job, Username ORDER BY ID), 0) AS DiffAmount
FROM
    @t t1
ORDER BY
   t1.ID
```

For "first value" per pair

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    CASE
        WHEN FIRST_VALUE(t1.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Job, Username ORDER BY ID) = t1.ID THEN t1.Amount
        ELSE t1.Amount - FIRST_VALUE(t1.Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Job, Username ORDER BY ID)
    END AS DiffAmount
FROM
    @t t1
ORDER BY
    t1.ID
```

Comment: The Amounts are individual to the User and are not Job Totals, so ID 5 and 6 are correct.  There is also a Date field (and others) but I didn't include in order to keep the sample data concise.

Comment: Despite all the arguments about arithmetic, the PARTITION and LAG keywords were what I was looking for and enabled me to draft a solution.

Comment: @PJW: we got there though... :-)